# Is there a function that can remove multiple rows based on multiple specific column values in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have a particular Pandas dataframe that has multiple different string categories in a particular column - 'A'. I want to create a new dataframe with only rows that contain 7 separate categories from column A out of about 15.

I know that I can individually remove/add categories using:

`df1 = df[df.Category != 'a']`

but I also tried using a list to try and do it in a single line, like such:

`df1 = df[df.Category = ['x','y','z']]`

but that gave me a syntax error. Is there any way to perform this function?

Comment: see my answer but just an fyi, you need to do `==` instead of `=` like this `df1 = df[df.Category == ['x','y','z']]`

Comment: Oh right, silly of me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df1 = df[df.Category.isin(['x','y','z'])]
```